# Sencha Touch code run in eclipse emulator

Tags: eclipse, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am using sencha touch to build an android app. I have successfully build an ios app using sencha command. Now moving to android version. I dont know how can i run sencha project in eclipse emulator. I did some googling, but did not get any step by step method to run sencha code in eclipse. I woud like to preview my code in emulator. I have downloaded android sdk manager and its working fine. How can include one sencha sample project in to eclipse and run in android virtual device manager. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i moved my Sencha-touch 2 app from iOS to Android (via Eclipse). I had to wrap my app in `PhoneGap`.

Check out these links:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

http://blogformobile.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/moving-sencha-touch-2-to-phonegap/

http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/

One of them worked for me. I think it was the first one, combined with number two.

Comment: i tried your first link, it almost working. i will let you know if there is any problems... thanks